# Convert Json to scala object

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework-2.1

I have the following Json string:

```
{
  "references": {
    "configuratorId": "conf id",
    "seekId": "seekid",
    "hsId": "hsid",
    "fpId": "fpid"
  }
}
```

And i want to create an object from it in my Rest API Controller.

The code:

```
case class References(configuratorId: Option[String], seekId: Option[String], hsId: Option[String], fpId: Option[String]) {}
```

The Formatter:

```
trait ProductFormats extends ErrorFormats {
  implicit val referencesFormat = Json.format[References]

implicit val referenceFormat = new Format[References]{
def writes(item: References):JsValue = {
  Json.obj(
      "configuratorId" -> item.configuratorId,
      "seekId" -> item.seekId,
      "hsId" -> item.hsId,
      "fpId" -> item.fpId
      )
}
def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[References] = 
JsSuccess(new References(
    (json \ "configuratorId").as[Option[String]],
    (json \ "seekId").as[Option[String]],
    (json \ "hsId").as[Option[String]],
    (json \ "fpId").as[Option[String]]
    ))
    }
```

Code in my controller:

```
def addProducts(lang: String, t: String) = Action {
  request =>
    request.body.asJson.map {
      json =>
        val req = json.as[References]
        println(req.configuratorId.getOrElse("it was empty !!"))
        Ok(Json.toJson((req)))
    }.getOrElse {
      println("Bad json:" + request.body.asText.getOrElse("No data in body"))
      BadRequest("Incorrect json data")
    }
}
```

The object is full with null values.. I guess my reads is wrong - but i cant figure out why.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the code in your controller to:

```
val req = (json \ "references").as[References]
```